# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_sftp'

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to fetch the data from SFTP from some particular folder but getting the  following issue:

File "/usr/local/airflow/plugins/kyber/sftp_to_s3_operator.py", line 59, in execute
 sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_sftp'

Comment: It is caused because `ssh_client` is `None`, so check its value.

Comment: hope its clear now.

Comment: Is it a script that you wrote or a part of a library?

Comment: I checked the value of SSH_CLEINT; its None.
Any reasons why it is coming as None

Comment: @YogeshSharma that would depend on what you set it to be in your code. Maybe look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
apt-get install openssh-client
```

cause sftp it's a service from SSH (secure FTP)

Comment: The question is about Python SFTP **client library** (pysftp), not about a **server**.